# Big5 to utf-8 encoding while scraping website with Node-request

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8

I am new to Node.js, and I am trying to use the request model to scrap a website, I am having problem with the encoding: the target website is using big5 as encoding, and I wished to turn it to utf-8 with the following code:

```
var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
var fs = require('fs');
var big5_to_utf8 = new Iconv('big5', 'utf-8');
var buffer = big5_to_utf8.convert(fs.readFileSync('./test'));
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

I doubt that the problem might be caused due to some wrong in the scrapping process, so for your reference, my code for scrapping:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var j = request.jar()
var cookie = request.cookie('ASPSESSIONIDCSDCTTSR=KDMMMIMDCCIHJIJFDKGEDFOH')
j.add(cookie)

request({
    url: 'http://amis.afa.gov.tw/v-asp/v101r.asp',
    method: "POST",
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;",
    jar:true,
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    form: {
        mhidden1:false,
        myy:101,
        mmm:9,
        mdd:25,
        mpno:"FC",
        mpnoname:"%ADJ%A5%CA++++",
        B1:"%B6%7D%A9l%ACd%B8%DF",
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    fs.writeFile("test", body);
});
```

Really appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific to the error, the following are what the code returns:

```
<p align="center"><font color="#800080">�Шϥ��s�����u���C��</font><em><font
size="4" color="#000080">[�W�@��]</font></em><font color="#800080">�^���e�@���J�����e���~���d��</font></p>
```

This is what it should return:

```
<p align="center"><font color="#800080">請使用瀏覽器工具列中</font><em><font size="4" color="#000080">[上一頁]</font></em><font color="#800080">回到前一輸入條件畫面繼續查詢</font></p>
```

I also tried to use iconv-lite instead of iconv, replacing the function call to the following:

```
function (error, response, body) {
    var bufferhelper = new BufferHelper();
    bufferhelper.concat(body);
    console.log(iconv.decode(bufferhelper.toBuffer(), 'Big5'));
});
```

Only to get:

```
<p align="center"><font color="#800080">�濆詉胬胬譃胬舚胬</font><em><font
size="4" color="#000080">[抝胬]</font></em><font color="#800080">䒷胬蓚胬鸜胬胬蓚胬趦胬胬</font</p>
```

Comment: Did you verify that the data is actually encoded under big5?

Comment: To Nirk: I just checked again, yes, the page is encoded under big5.

Comment: `I am having a problem`, describe the exact problem you are facing. What is the result of your code. Do you get any error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use `iconv-lite` to decode big5 to utf8.

And you should set `encoding:null` that `request` will return raw encoding page.

This is sample code.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var request = require('request');
request({ url: 'http://amis.afa.gov.tw/v-asp/v101r.asp',encoding:null}, function(err,     response, body) {
  if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var str = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "big5");
    console.log(str);
  }
});
```

And return is

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
<title>v101r</title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="none, default">
</head>

<body>
<p align="center">查無結果!</p>

<p align="center"><font color="#800080">請使用瀏覽器工具列中</font><em><font
size="4" color="#000080">[上一頁]</font></em><font color="#800080">回到前一輸入條件畫面繼續查詢</font></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I use `node.js 0.10.20` on `RedHat EL 6.4` and  `iconv-lite 0.2.11`, `request 2.27.0`

Comment: Ran into exact same problem as OP, tried Iconv's Big5HKSCS (scraping from an HK site) to UTF8 converter and didn't work, but this fixed it! Many thanks indeed!!

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest my [codepage library](https://npmjs.org/package/codepage):

```
var request = require('request'), codepage = require('codepage')
request({ url: 'http://amis.afa.gov.tw/v-asp/v101r.asp',encoding:null}, function(err,     response, body) {
  if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var str = codepage.utils.decode(950, new Buffer(body));
    console.log(str);
  }
});
```

yields

```
... <p align="center"><font color="#800080">請使用瀏覽器工具列中</font><em><font
size="4" color="#000080">[上一頁]</font></em><font color="#800080">回到前一輸入條件畫面繼續查詢</font></p>
```